# Dynamic WriteStrategy for MongoDB Sink connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

Is there a way to dynamically choose the WriteStrategy of a MongoDB sink connector?

Use case at hand -

Read from a topic and write to mongo atlas using mongodb sink connector in a way that the ordering of these writes is kept intact in the way that the events occured on a given partition of the source topic. The source topic will be partitioned on the business key that is then used to do one of the below 3 on atlas -

1. Insert new Document (possibly use InsertOneDefaultStrategy)
2. Update an existing document based on business key (possibly use UpdateOneBusinessKeyTimestampStrategy)
3. Delete an existing document based on business key (possibly use DeleteOneBusinessKeyStrategy)

I am also thinking if I could use ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy to keep things easier - but it doesnt satisfy the delete requirement - for which I am contemplating if I should do some sort of soft deletes.

Writing a custom write strategy is another option - but not sure if I want to invest time and effort in coming up with something custom.

I cannot have multiple source topics for each event type for ordering concerns.

It would have been nice if I could choose Write strategies dynamically based on some header or metadata field in the input message.

Any suggestions or feedback are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you'll have to invest some time to write a custom write strategy. There is the `topic.override.<topic>.<property>` setting where you can specify different settings for different topics, ie writemodel strategy.

I guess the easiest way is to include a document field that describes an action that you want to perform, and apply the relevant action to the document.